# HTML5 canvas, непонятно применяется шрифт к повёрнутым текстам

Tags: canvas

Делаю часы, нужно разметить циферблат заданным шрифтом. Каждую секунду запускается скрипт, который перерисовывает циферблат. 
Текст поворачивается как надо, но нужный шрифт не применяется в `Firefox`, а в `Chrome` применяется только на вторую и последующие секунды, при дальнейших обновлениях в `Chrome` отображается сразу. 
Устранил возможности отставания загрузки шрифта, поместив его и сам скрипт в html.

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так, и как сделать правильно.

**Добавлено**

Решение оказалось неожиданным: в настройках Firefox стояло принудительное использование заданного шрифта... Код в этом вопросе - рабочий.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <title>Часы</title>
 <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = utf-8" >
 <style>
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Dorsa';
      src: url(data:font/woff2;base64,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) format('woff2');
      font-style: normal;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function displayCanvas(){
      var canvasHTML = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var contextHTML = canvasHTML.getContext('2d');
      contextHTML.strokeRect(0,0,canvasHTML.width, canvasHTML.height);

      var radiusClock = canvasHTML.width/2 - 40;
      var xCenterClock = canvasHTML.width/2;
      var yCenterClock = canvasHTML.height/2;

      contextHTML.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
      contextHTML.fillRect(0,0,canvasHTML.width,canvasHTML.height);

      contextHTML.font = '30px Dorsa';  //'bold 12px sans-serif '
      contextHTML.fillStyle = '#000000';
      contextHTML.textAlign = 'center';
   
      var text = "Half circle Text"; 
      var space = 0;
      var top = 1;
      var numRadsPerLetter = (Math.PI - space * 2) / text.length;
      contextHTML.save();
      contextHTML.translate(xCenterClock,yCenterClock);
      var k = (top) ? 1 : -1; 
      contextHTML.rotate(-k * ((Math.PI - numRadsPerLetter) / 2 - space));
      for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
       contextHTML.save();
       contextHTML.rotate(k*i*(numRadsPerLetter));
       contextHTML.textAlign = "center";
       contextHTML.textBaseline = (!top) ? "top" : "bottom";
       contextHTML.fillText(text[i],0,-k*(radiusClock));
       contextHTML.restore();
      }
      contextHTML.restore();
                   return;
  }

  window.onload = function(){
       window.setInterval(
   function(){
    displayCanvas();
   }
      , 1000);
  }
 </script>
  </head> 
  <body>
     
 
 <canvas height='600' width='600' id='myCanvas'></canvas>

  </body>
</html>
```

Часы
    
    
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Dorsa';
            src: srl(data:font/woff2;base64,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) format('woff2');
            font-style: normal;
        }
    
    
        function displayCanvas(){
            var canvasHTML = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var contextHTML = canvasHTML.getContext('2d');
            contextHTML.strokeRect(0,0,canvasHTML.width, canvasHTML.height);

```
        var radiusClock = canvasHTML.width/2 - 40;
        var xCenterClock = canvasHTML.width/2;
        var yCenterClock = canvasHTML.height/2;

        contextHTML.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        contextHTML.fillRect(0,0,canvasHTML.width,canvasHTML.height);

        contextHTML.font = '30px Dorsa';  //'bold 12px sans-serif '
        contextHTML.fillStyle = '#000000';
        contextHTML.textAlign = 'center';

        var text = "Half circle Text"; 
        var space = 0;
        var top = 1;
        var numRadsPerLetter = (Math.PI - space * 2) / text.length;
        contextHTML.save();
        contextHTML.translate(xCenterClock,yCenterClock);
        var k = (top) ? 1 : -1; 
        contextHTML.rotate(-k * ((Math.PI - numRadsPerLetter) / 2 - space));
        for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
            contextHTML.save();
            contextHTML.rotate(k*i*(numRadsPerLetter));
            contextHTML.textAlign = "center";
            contextHTML.textBaseline = (!top) ? "top" : "bottom";
            contextHTML.fillText(text[i],0,-k*(radiusClock));
            contextHTML.restore();
        }
       contextHTML.restore();
               return;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
            window.setInterval(
        function(){
            displayCanvas();
        }
        , 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Посмотреть можно [здесь](http://whiteplane.su/clock_test/)

Comment: _"через секунду меняется на нужный"_ -- наверное потому что он подгружается с сайта fonts.gstatic.com

Comment: "наверное потому что он подгружается с сайта fonts.gstatic.com" - это первое что пришло в голову , клал шрифт локально, перекодировал в .ttf , брал другой шрифт - без изменений и в Firefox не срабатывает.

Comment: а если сделать кнопку на странице. дождаться пока шрифт подгрузится и отобразится. и нажать кнопку для вызова displayCanvas(). тоже не выводится в канвас?

Comment: Изменил window.onload , перед запуском window.setInterval поместил код javascript из google fonts , удалил содержимое css. На сколько понимаю, шрифт загружается прежде чем стартует canvas. В **Chrome** отображется сразу, в **Firefox** не работает как и прежде.  [Загрузил новую версию](http://whiteplane.su/clock_test/)

Comment: Поместил шрифт и скрипт в `html` , исключив тем самым загрузку в отставании. Проблема осталась. [Загрузил новую версию](http://whiteplane.su/clock_test/).

Comment: Замена windows.onload на document.onload проблему не решает?

Comment: "Замена windows.onload на document.onload проблему не решает?"  Так вообще ни чего не отображается ни в одном ни в другом браузере.

Comment: Похожий вопрос : [Drawing text to <canvas> with @font-face does not work at the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time).

Comment: Решение оказалось неожиданным: в настройках Firefox стояло принудительное использование заданного шрифта... Код в тексте вопроса - рабочий.